# Gradle/Eclipse issue when importing projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Have been using Gradle with Eclipse on a multi-project development effort for over two years.  During that time, every once in a while (maybe after changing branches too often) Eclipse gets confused.  Deleting the projects (not their contents) and re-importing fixes it every time.  Typically, I have needed to do this about once every two months.  No big deal!  Import is done within Eclipse via the Import->Gradle Project -> build model process.

I needed to do this again recently after upgrading to the latest packages.  Now compilation and execution (running Unit Tests for instance) within Eclipse works fine; but debug has lost all the inter-project dependencies.  I can no longer set a breakpoint on code in Project 2 and run something from Project 1 and have the source code display.  Instead, I get the "Edit Source Lookup Path" window when the breakpoint is hit.

I have Eclipse Luna Release 2, version 4.4.2, Spring IDE 3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE, and Gradle IDE 3.6.4.201503050952-RELEASE.  My gradle wrapper is version 2.3.6, and I am on a Mac OS X 10.10.3

The previous .classpath files looked like:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/classes/main" path="src/generated/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/classes/main" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/resources/main" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/classes/test" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="build/resources/test" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="src" path="/proj1.main"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="src" path="/proj2.main"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="src" path="/proj3.main"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target"/>
```

which has three dependent projects then show up on the Java Build Path, Projects tab.  Now, none show up but the projects appear under Gradle Dependencies on the Libraries tab (so compiling and running still works).

I imported the same way I have for over two years, so that is not it.  Additionally, there are some new options on the Preferences->Gradle tab.  I tried with "Remap Jars to Gradle Projects" and "Use Custom Tooling Model).

Does anyone know how to make it work the way it has been working?  I really do not want to generate the eclipse files from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

try cleanEclipse and also check the .bin directory and see if the class files are there as this is how gradle plugin use to debug.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to mention that via the gradle import I do: cleanEclipse eclipse as two "Run Before" tasks and 'afterEclipseImport' as a "Run After" task